# Enumeration.values adds a value to set when called twice?

Tags: scala

```
scala> object Foo extends Enumeration {
     | val Bar = Value(23)
     | val Moo = Value(57)
     | }
defined module Foo

scala> Foo.values
res27: Foo.ValueSet = Foo.ValueSet(Bar, Moo)
```

So far as expected. But then (continuing from above):

```
scala> Foo.values
res28: Foo.ValueSet = Foo.ValueSet(Bar, Moo, Value)
```

What just happened?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 2.9.0.1 - what version of scala are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.8.1. Just checked with 2.9.0, cannot be reproduced. So I assume it was a bug in < 2.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Scala 2.8.1.  See the [issue on JIRA](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3687).